# Как получить список изменённых файлов?

Tags: git

Можно ли получить список изменённых файлов в диапазоне определённых коммитов?
т.е. нужно получить изменённые файлы после того, как был сделан пуш этих файлов, чтобы можно было указать, с какого по какой пуш выбрать файлы

Comment: `git show --name-only HEAD~5..HEAD~1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить голый список файлов:

```
git diff --name-only hash1 hash2
```

В каком коммите, что менялось:

```
git show --oneline --name-only hash1..hash2
```

Будьте внимательны, в списке будут присутствовать все затронутые файлы, включая удалённые.
Если интересует, что именно произошло с файлами, смените ключ `--name-only` на `--name-status`

Comment: `--diff-filter=...`